# Forcing autocomplete to lose focus after selecting from suggestions

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Very basic stuff, but I can't get my head around it.

After calling:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#aspecinput").autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'd like autocomplete to lose focus immediately, after the selection gets in the field because I have an onblur event on my search window that needs to run to adjust the selected data. Right now, I have to lose focus by clicking anywhere within the webpage obviously, to lose focus from the search textfield. How can I achieve the results?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

instead of loosing focus you can do this, make use of `change` function

```
$('#aspecinput').change(function(){   
    //fire search click 
    //or fire function to do search
});
```

or try this make use of 'select' function

```
$('#aspecinput').autocomplete({
    'select':function(){
        $('#aspecinput').blur();
    }
});
```

Comment: I might have not described it correctly. Everything works fine, the data I select enters the field, but I don't want the users to click outside the input area in order to have their data formatted properly (via the onblur function I call when they click out). If there is a way to do it automatically after clicking the selected result item from the autocomplete dropdown as normally, I am sure there is, I'll be a happy bunny.

Comment: @BalazsDavidKalvin - check the answer you can make use of the function  on select as suggested...

Comment: It is not working unfortunately. :/ Focus still blinks on search field with selected information in it, after selecting from the autocomplete dropdown.

Comment: @BalazsDavidKalvin - answer is updated try  $('#aspecinput').blur(); in select function

Comment: Sorry, but this one is a no go either. :)

Comment: It's ok, i'll try to figure it out, any more help would be appreciated!